# Android - How to initialize sliding menu only once

Tags: android, fragment, slidingmenu

I am using this sliding menu in my project

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

I am adding this menu to all of my activities. And this sliding menu is calling a Fragment at opening. How to prevent creating multiple fragments for each activity and call if Fragment is already created at back stack ?

Each of my activities are extending my BaseActivity and i'm initialzing sliding menu like this at BaseActivity.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detail, new DetailFragment())
    .commit();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (at least) try to implement only *one* activity and replace various fragments within the content frame. You should know that the example contains various approaches from one you should choose *one* ;)

So having a menu and content fragment you could start as below (compare `ResponsiveUIActivity` too).

```
public class StartActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        Fragment contentFragment = InitialFragment()

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuFragment()).commit();

        ...
    }

    public void switchContent(final Fragment fragment) {
        // replace fragment in content frame
        ...
    }
```

In the menu fragment, you can create new fragments according to the users choice (compare `BirdMenuFragment`):

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        Fragment newContent = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 1 : new ThisFragment();
                     break;
            case 2 : new ThatFragment();
                     break;
            case 3 : new AnotherFragment();
                     break;
        }

        if (newContent != null) switchFragment(newContent);
    }

    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // call StartActivity.switchContent
        ...
    }
```

Finally, the glue between activity and menu fragment is `MenuFragment.switchFragment(Fragment fragment)` and `StartActivity.switchContent(final Fragment fragment)` whereas the menu fragment method calls the activity method for replacing the content fragment in the content frame (compare classes`BirdMenuFragment` and `ResponsiveUIActivity` in the example).

This is just an outline of how you could implement the SlidingMenu and how you could replace the fragments in the content frame. There are of course some challenges left to cope with.

Anyway I hope I could help a bit ... Cheers!

Comment: Can you please explain more :) What is newFragment here and how to replace fragment in content frame.

Comment: Look at this one: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/ResponsiveUIActivity.java for `switchContent()` and this one: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/BirdMenuFragment.java for `switchFragment()`; in addition I fixed this one: `new contentFragment` above - there should be no `new`. What do you mean by `newFragment`? I didn't use that.

Comment: Okey, i understand more now. In my code i don't have different fragments. I have activities. For examle ListActivity is extending BaseActivity , how can i switch content at ListActivity ?

Comment: Instead of switching fragments in the `case` statement above, you could of course start intents for activities too - or mix both together, e.g. `case 2 : Intent intent = new Intent(...); ... startActivity(intent); break;`. However, using fragments is definitely the recommended way. If you have activities and you want to have a SlidingMenu on all of them, you'd have to instantiate a SlidingMenu in all activities - preferably implemented once in the `BaseActivity`. But this has disadvantages, e.g. in case you want to populate any information to the menu (for instance indicators).

Comment: tried it. but how to change content(for activities) in switchContent function ? in these examples they are replacing old fragments not activities.

Comment: If you use an intent to start a new activity, you don't need the `switchContent()` method. So looking at my code above you could also had a *return* in that case: `case 2 : Intent intent ...; return;`. `switchFragment()` is used to replace a fragment in the content frame (see layout at https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/res/layout/content_frame.xml) assuming that you use only one activity, and switch multiple fragments inside that activity (namely `StartActivity`). You can mix both approaches, however with starting an intent, there is no `switchContent()` involved.