# (android) manipulate other activites through sliding menu (listfragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

By using sliding menu library (list fragment)https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu, how can I manipulate other activities through it? Let's say I want to make a button in the main activity to be invisible with `button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);` What should I do in the sliding menu(List fragment) to achieve it? So far I only know how to Toast..

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to send a broadcast from the menu:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
intent.putExtra("visibility", View.GONE);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and process it in the intent in your fragment or activity:

```
package com.example.BroadcastDetector;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Implement code here to be performed when 
        // broadcast is detected
    }
}
```

Have a look at [this site](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers) for a `BroadcastReceiver` example.

However, when implementing a `SlindingMenu`, you typically have your menu and a content fragment in the same activity. This way you can simply reference the currently shown fragment:

```
public class StartActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        Fragment contentFragment = InitialFragment()

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuFragment()).commit();

        ...
    }

    public void switchContent(final Fragment fragment) {
        // replace fragment in content frame or perform changes on it
        ...
    }
```

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365749/android-how-to-initialize-sliding-menu-only-once) for further details.